# Print key and value pairs of dictionary separately in ajax resposne

Tags: python, html, ajax, templates

This is my dictionary

`[{'entity': 'first entity', 'place': 'first palce'}, {'entity': 'second entity', 'place': 'second place'}]`

I want to pass it to Html template file and I am passing as below

`return(dict(docs=docs))`

How can I iterate through Ajax to print key, value separately??

I tried this, but not working

```
 function f(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.get('ajx', function(response){ 

     $.each(response, function(key, value) {

        alert(key+' '+ value);
         });

     });
 });
}
```

I tried to use `jQuery.parseJson()` but not working!!!

Comment: Use `getJSON` instead of `get`. Use `response` instead of `respose`. And use an inner loop - the loop you have will give you the two entities, then you have to iterate again to get their keys and values.

Comment: respose?? I have used response

Comment: What's the connection with Python? Looks like JavaScript to me. Or are you using Django (then add that as a keyword)

Comment: `$.each(respose, function(key, value) {`

Comment: Actually, it would be really nice if you could take a look at the response in the network console and report exactly what is being sent by the server.

Comment: @Amadan it was a typo, it is `$.each(response, function(key, value) {`

Comment: @Amadan, Could you elaborate your first comment or give me an example as in what is that regarding inner loop??

Comment: @UserAR, could you do as I asked in my previous comment and reported exactly what is being sent by the server from the browser's Developer Tools Network panel?

Comment: @Amadan, is this what you are asking about? I got this when I saw from  Developer Tools Network panel Response window ` 
{"docs": [{"entity": "first entity", "place": "first palce"}, {"entity": "second entity", "place": "second place"}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enumerate all the nested keys and values from that, you should do this:

```
$.each(response.docs, function(index, element) {
  $.each(element, function(key, value) {
    console.log("At index", index, "key:", key, "value:", value);
  });
});
```

(I prefer `console.log` to `alert` - too much noise.)

Comment: Ah!! figured it out. It should be `$.each(element, function(key, value) {` missing a dot there. Thanks a lot @Amadan :)

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry about the typo. Must have been unconscious payback for `respose` :P Fixed now.

Comment: If you could clear it, I have one more concern, I'm using html template file and want to print it there. console.log doesn't work for me @Amadan

Comment: Then neither would `alert`. "html template file" is very vague, and I am not a mind reader. :) Please show the template, and the code you would have used to render it.

Comment: Meaning, I have saved the file with the extension .tpl in which the above code is placed. Alert works fine not the console.log